# carousel javascript several times

Tags: javascript, carousel, forum

I wanna use this carousel :
    `[http://codepen.io/ScottMarshall/pen/FwxpH][1]`     
on a forum, but when I repeat the code, it doesn't work well. 
Can you help me ?

here, it's working, but the second container doesn't want and I don't want to change anything in the HTML...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x6251wc/1/)

Comment: Show the code you are using that doesn't work, works fine in the demo.

Comment: Sorry, I've add the code right now, thank you!

Comment: You just copied in the code from the pen, you must be using it incorrectly in your site.  Build a jsfiddle with the actual code you are trying to use on your site.

Comment: here it's working but not several times T.T

`http://jsfiddle.net/1x6251wc/1/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1x6251wc/2/

This is the key change to get the context "Front" instead of all of them:

```
var $front = $this.parent().find(".Front");
```

It's a poorly written plugin, but this change should get it to work across multiple instances.

Comment: thank you very muuuch ! That was all I need, thank you thank you thank you ! ♥